# Crop video stream using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

We need to rebroadcast rtsp stream to rtmp and it is working OK, but now we need to crop about 10 pixels from each side. We are using the below parameters, but it is not working:

```
ffmpeg  -i rtsp://admin:admin145@192.178.9.2/MPEG-4/ch1/main/av_stream  -vf crop=in_w-2*10:in_h-2*10 -c copy -s 270x155 -tune zerolatency -f flv -an rtmp://174.127.117.102:1935/hls_1/live
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you filter a stream, you have to re-encode it, so

```
... -vf crop=in_w-2*10:in_h-2*10 -c:v h264 -c:a copy ...
```

Also, libx264 needs dimensions to be even, so 155 in `-s` should be changed to 154.